# Как привязать к ключу строки матрицы? В данном случае, выдаётся ячейка переменной

Tags: c++

```
unsigned short numberTable[WIDTH_HEIGHT][WIDTH_HEIGHT];
for(short i = 0;i<WIDTH_HEIGHT;i++){
    for(short j = 0;j<WIDTH_HEIGHT;j++){
        numberTable[i][j] = j+1;
    }
}
for( short i = 0;i<WIDTH_HEIGHT;i++){
    for(short j = 0;j<WIDTH_HEIGHT;j++){
        std::cout<<unsigned(numberTable[i][j]);
    }
    std::cout<<'\n';
}
std::map<short,unsigned short(*)[WIDTH_HEIGHT]> gameTable;
for(short i = 0;i<WIDTH_HEIGHT;i++){
    gameTable[i+1] = &numberTable[i];  
}
std::map<short,unsigned short(*)[WIDTH_HEIGHT]>::iterator itr = gameTable.begin();
while(itr!=gameTable.end()){
    std::cout<<itr->second<<'\n';
    ++itr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::map<short, unsigned short*> gameTable;
for (short i = 0; i < WIDTH_HEIGHT; i++) {
    gameTable[i + 1] = numberTable[i];
}
auto itr = gameTable.begin();
while (itr != gameTable.end()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH_HEIGHT; ++i)
         std::cout << itr->second[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    ++itr;
}
```

Но если хотите хранить тип массив, то `itr->second` это адрес массива, разыменовывая получите сам массив, и нужно еще обращаться к элементам этого массива. А значит:

```
std::map<short, unsigned short(*)[WIDTH_HEIGHT]> gameTable;
for (short i = 0; i < WIDTH_HEIGHT; i++) {
    gameTable[i + 1] = &numberTable[i];
}
std::map<short, unsigned short(*)[WIDTH_HEIGHT]>::iterator itr = gameTable.begin();
while (itr != gameTable.end()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH_HEIGHT; ++i)
        std::cout << (*itr->second)[i] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
    ++itr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Всегда лучше хранить еще тип массива, мы обращаемся к second в 
itr (адрес массива). и нужно к элементам самого массива обратиться.

```
std::map<short, unsigned short(*)[WIDTH_HEIGHT]> gameTable;
for (short i = 0; i < WIDTH_HEIGHT; i++) {
    gameTable[i + 1] = &numberTable[i];
}
std::map<short, unsigned short(*)[WIDTH_HEIGHT]>::iterator itr = gameTable.begin();
while (itr != gameTable.end()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH_HEIGHT; ++i)
        std::cout << (*itr->second)[i] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
    ++itr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А если пользователь  `Fameek` не захотел бы повторить часть моего ответа, то мог бы написать другой вариант, например такой:

```
std::map<short, unsigned short(*)[WIDTH_HEIGHT]> gameTable;
for (short i = 0; i < WIDTH_HEIGHT; i++) {
    gameTable[i + 1] = &numberTable[i];
}   
for (auto p : gameTable) {
    for (unsigned short el : *p.second) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```